# not able to run the tomcat due to query QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm recently upgrading my application so I have upgraded the hibernate and spring data, earlier the query was working fine but now not able to solve this error. Error in eclipse while running the tomcat:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.demoweb.backend.repository.GradeRepository.getActiveGrades(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Boolean)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:575)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:568)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1051)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:570)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:560)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:560)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'studentBO.isDeletedFromSync' [select grade.gradeName from com.demoweb.backend.model.GradeBO grade where grade.gradeName <> '' and grade in (select studentBo.gradeBO from com.demoweb.backend.model.StudentBO studentBo where studentBo.id in(select userBo.id from com.demoweb.backend.model.UserBO userBo where userBo.role='STUDENT' and userBo.active=:isActive and userBo.schoolBO.id=:schoolId) and (studentBO.isDeletedFromSync is null or studentBO.isDeletedFromSync=false))]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

the query :-

```
@Query("select grade.gradeName from GradeBO grade where grade.gradeName <> '' and grade in (select studentBo.gradeBO from StudentBO studentBo where studentBo.id in(select userBo.id from UserBO userBo where userBo.role='STUDENT' and userBo.active=:isActive and userBo.schoolBO.id=:schoolId) and (studentBO.isDeletedFromSync is null or studentBO.isDeletedFromSync=false))")
    List<String> getActiveGrades(@Param("schoolId") Long schoolId, @Param("isActive") Boolean isActive);
```

i tried changing the query but didn't work

```
("select grade.gradeName from GradeBO grade where grade.gradeName <> '' and grade in (select studentBo.gradeBO from StudentBO studentBo where studentBo.id in(select userBo.id from UserBO userBo where userBo.role='STUDENT' and userBo.active=:isActive and userBo.schoolBO.id=:schoolId and (studentBO.isDeletedFromSync is null or studentBO.isDeletedFromSync=false)))")
```

Comment: Can you share the studentBO definition?  Looking at your exception I would say that it is not existing "isDeletedFromSync" could be that is called actually deletedFromSync the property?

Comment: @Column(name="IS_DELETED_FROM_SYNC")
 private Boolean isDeletedFromSync;
its present in BO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
and (studentBO.isDeletedFromSync is null or studentBO.isDeletedFromSync=false))")
```

use this:-

```
and (studentBo.isDeletedFromSync is null or studentBo.isDeletedFromSync=false))")
```

you have used 'studentBo' in as clause.